# loop to extract some parts in dictionary in JSON

Tags: python

I have as well as 1500 elements in JSON format, but I need to put in on a dictionary in python. Each element is associated with an ID (which is also in a dictionary and is a polygon representation).

The elements have the same structure:

```
OrderedDict([('d5b6d112-903b-4648-833e-d7c3fdac490b',
              {'title': 'S2A_MSIL1C_20200410T105031_N0209_R051_T31TCF_20200410T112156',
               'link': "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('d5b6d112-903b-4648-833e-d7c3fdac490b')/$value",
               'link_alternative': "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('d5b6d112-903b-4648-833e-d7c3fdac490b')/",
               'link_icon': "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('d5b6d112-903b-4648-833e-d7c3fdac490b')/Products('Quicklook')/$value",
               'summary': 'Date: 2020-04-10T10:50:31.024Z, Instrument: MSI, Mode: , Satellite: Sentinel-2, Size: 708.56 MB',
               'datatakesensingstart': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 10, 10, 50, 31, 24000),
               'beginposition': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 10, 10, 50, 31, 24000),
               'endposition': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 10, 10, 50, 31, 24000),
               'ingestiondate': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 10, 15, 23, 51, 463000),
               'orbitnumber': 25073,
               'relativeorbitnumber': 51,
               'cloudcoverpercentage': 25.1653,
               'sensoroperationalmode': 'INS-NOBS',
               'gmlfootprint': '<gml:Polygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">\n   <gml:outerBoundaryIs>\n      <gml:LinearRing>\n         <gml:coordinates>41.12630256662179,1.925343307665624 41.0388866778506,1.893218517758493 40.89259720303277,1.839655652731482 40.74637877387899,1.786307008717412 40.60020137146172,1.733323787214736 40.554608185948275,1.716936587906194 40.538607851727775,0.638419022640916 41.52685230149302,0.6028173807795 41.546758769895376,1.918508192616414 41.12630256662179,1.925343307665624</gml:coordinates>\n      </gml:LinearRing>\n   </gml:outerBoundaryIs>\n</gml:Polygon>',
               'footprint': 'MULTIPOLYGON (((0.638419022640916 40.538607851727775, 1.716936587906194 40.554608185948275, 1.733323787214736 40.60020137146172, 1.786307008717412 40.74637877387899, 1.839655652731482 40.89259720303277, 1.893218517758493 41.0388866778506, 1.925343307665624 41.12630256662179, 1.918508192616414 41.546758769895376, 0.6028173807795 41.52685230149302, 0.638419022640916 40.538607851727775)))',
```

I need extract: Title, footprint and datatakesensingstart. I would like all the extracted elements to be stored in a list.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Could you provide JSON file?

Comment: You say ordered, do you mean maintaining the order that is in the JSON file, or sorted by something else?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list of `OrderedDict` objects following the structure you mention, you could use a list comprehension to create a list of trimmed-down dictionaries containing only the keys you are interested in.

```py
trimmed_data = [
    {
        'Title': element[1]['Title'],
        'footprint': element[1]['footprint'],
        'datatakesensingstart': element[1]['datatakesensingstart'],
    }
    for element in data
]
```